# The button is not working to second click in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I'm using a tab control with updatepanel. I have got a diffirent event(selectedindexchange or click etc.)  That's why my page is postback.actually it works fine when I first click the button. But the second one doesn't work. Function does not enter(LinkButton5_Click).I tried trigger but not worked. Please help me! (Hesapla and Kaydet my LinkButton.)

```
                        <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:Panel ID="panelKayit" runat="server" Visible="false">
```

Hesapla

Kaydet

```
    </asp:Panel>

                        </ContentTemplate>

                        <Triggers>

                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton5" EventName="Click" />   

                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton6" EventName="Click" />  

                        </Triggers>

                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.